# (dojo) dojox.form.Manager not firing observers

Tags: dojo

I have a customer dialog widget that I am attempting to use `dojox.form.Manager` on.

I have just stumbled across this control and it looks to do most of what I was implementing (unified onchange events) but much more.  There is just one problem, the observer events will not fire.

I have a form element containing multiple digits, form, and custom widgets.  Each is set up something like

```
  <form id="resd_tab_details"dojoType="dojox.form.Manager">
        <input type="checkbox" dojoType="dijit.form.CheckBox" name="w01" value="w01"
        observer="testfunction1">
    </form>
```

I can attach to the form set values and everything else I have tried, except the events.

What might I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

IIRC an observer is a method name on a form manager, not a standalone function. While you didn't give the complete example to test, your naming suggest that you use a standalone function.

You can define a method on the form manager either inline (see an example in its "tests" subdirectory), or in the code by subclassing a manager.

Answer (score 0):

like this...

js portion

```
    dojo.mixin(dijit.byId('frmMngr1'), {
            'prvUpdate':function(){
                console.log("clicked a check box");
            }
        })
```

html portion:

```
    <form dojoType='dojox.form.Manager' id='frmMngr1'><input dojoType='dijit.form.CheckBox' observer='prvUpdate' checked name='title' />
```